# Schema design for timeseries database

Tags: database-design, time-series

I am designing a solution to store data collected from devices and am currently contemplating on the schema design. In particular, my problem is with storing instances of the same metric. For example, when collecting the current CPU load of an 8-core chip, the metric "cpu_load" will arrive to the DB 8 times for the same datetime. I would like to have the following timeseries table structure (not yet sure if Timescale or InfluxDB), but am not sure how to treat the instances of the same metric:

1. time,
2. device_id,
3. metric_id,
4. value

I'm sure this is a common scenario, but I can't seem to find an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about elegant, but here's simple.

```
Value
-----
Value ID
Device ID
Metric ID
Timestamp
Value
```

Where Value ID is an autoincrementing integer primary key and you have a unique index on (Device ID, Metric ID, Timestamp descending).